# How to rotate sprite based on phone rotation

Tags: ios, swift, rotation, accelerometer, core-motion

I am trying to rotate a sprite based on the iPhone's rotation (roll).
How would I go by doing this in swift (4.2)? I found Apple documentation using CMAttitude, but I don't understand how to implement this into code.
Any help is appreciated, 
Thanks!!!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> "You access CMAttitude objects through the attitude property of each CMDeviceMotion objects passed to an application."

See the [official documentation](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/coremotion/cmattitude)

Have a look at **[CMDeviceMotion](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/coremotion/cmdevicemotion)** - that is what is really necessary!

You need the *CMMotionManager* to receive what you want.
Maybe is [this link](https://nshipster.com/cmdevicemotion/) or [this tutorial](https://forestgiant.com/articles/ios-core-motion/) helpful for you.
 -> everything you need to know, to get started with DeviceMotions

Additional:
Think you re at SKit, that has the function [rotate](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/spritekit/skaction/1417805-rotate).

Simple as that:
based on the rotation of the phone you could
 - start rotation clockwise or counterclockwise
 - stop the rotation
 - and even change the rotation

```
  let angle : Float = (direction == yourDirection) ? Float(X) : -Float(X)
  let rotate = SKAction.rotateByAngle(angle, duration: 1)
  let repeatAction = SKAction.repeatActionForever(rotate)
  sprite.runAction(repeatAction, withKey: "rotate")
```

Comment: thanks, I understand how to get the phone's roll, but how would I implement that to the rotation of a sprite?

Comment: Please see the additional notes to my answer. You can set up the rotation for the sprite like that.

Comment: and what would yourDirection be?

Comment: e.g. clockwise. You need to set the direction according to the movement of the phone